# How to rerender a component in react-navigation when focus happen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to `useFocusEffect` to rerender a component in my view when I focus the view.

I did:

```
const [theKey, setTheKey] = useState(0);
```

Then:

```
useFocusEffect(() => { setTheKey(theKey + 1) }, [theKey]);
```

And the jsx:

```
<SwipeListView key={theKey} />
```

It does not work well, I have the errror: `Maximum update depth exceeded`

Can someone share a way to rerender it?

I do not have this issue with react router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is here:

```
useFocusEffect(() => { setTheKey(theKey + 1) }, [theKey]);
```

Inside this function you update `theKey`. And each time `theKey` gets updated the effect gets called again. This results in an infinite loop.

There are 2 solutions:

Remove theKey dependency:

```
useFocusEffect(
    () => { setTheKey(theKey + 1) }, 
    ["replace with something else"]
);
```

Add a condition before updating the state:

```
useFocusEffect(
    () => { if ("some condition") setTheKey(theKey + 1) }, 
    [theKey]
);
```

This will prevent the infinite loop.

Comment: What I finally did is `useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => { setTheKey(Math.random()); } , []))` and this work well, do you see any downside doing this?

Comment: It means useFocusEffect will only be called once. If that's your intention then this is fine.

Comment: I need it to be called once on focus, that's why I didn't get why onFocus was calling in loop just because the key change

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered issue with useFocusEffect. Either it triggers infinite loop / render, or it keeps a stale version of the function.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
const doSomething = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(count);
    setCount(count + 1);
}, [count]);

useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
        doSomething(); // Count will always be 1 (cached value)
    }, [doSomething])
);

useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
        doSomething(); // Latest count, but infinite loop due to doSomething() is recreated when count changes
    }, [doSomething])
);
```

Instead, can try with the combination of useIsFocus and usePrevious which works well with existing useEffect method.

```js
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

// usePrevious custom hook
function usePrevious(value) {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value;
    });
    return ref.current;
}

const isFocused = useIsFocused();
const prevIsFocused = usePrevious(isFocused);


useEffect(() => {
    if (!prevIsFocused && isFocused) {
        // Run your code here
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [isFocused]);
```